# Integrating jquery datepicker into jsf

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jsf-2

I was following the examples [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger) and [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger) but I cann't bring it to work. Could you help me please?

Here is where I define the script and below where I (suppose to) use it...

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#createDate" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
</script>

<ui:define name="columnFilters">
    <th>
        <h:inputText value="#{listModel.creationDate}" id="creationDate"
            valueChangeListener="#{listController.filterFieldChanged}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </th>
    <th>
        <h:inputText value="#{listModel.updateDate}" id="upateDate"
            valueChangeListener="#{listController.filterFieldChanged}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </th>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Unless you won't use the attribute forceid (or similar) = true, the JSF framework will create it's own id values. Those values will be assembled with your id and an intern randomly generated number. Btw. Check you HTML code, from your browser what object has been generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQuery ID selector must match exactly the generated HTML client ID, which you can see when you do rightclick and view source in browser.

Rather use a hook on the classname instead, this also allows you to select multiple elements. E.g.

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

with

```html
<h:inputText value="#{listModel.creationDate}" styleClass="datepicker"
    valueChangeListener="#{listController.filterFieldChanged}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText value="#{listModel.updateDate}" styleClass="datepicker"
    valueChangeListener="#{listController.filterFieldChanged}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Hello BalusC, I changed the code as you suggested and now my script looks like this: `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
          $(function()
          {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         showOn: "button",
         buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
         buttonImageOnly: true
     });
    });

         //]]>
     </script>`  But in the console of firebug I see "$(".datepicker").datepicker is not a function"... What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to import the necessary jQuery scripts by `<script>` in `<head>`.

Comment: This is a portion of my head and the scripts should be there (or not?) <script type="text/javascript" src="/doi-web/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=scripts"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/doi-web/javax.faces.resource/datepicker.js.xhtml?ln=scripts"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/doi-web/javax.faces.resource/eye.js.xhtml?ln=scripts"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/doi-web/javax.faces.resource/layout.js.xhtml?ln=scripts"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/doi-web/javax.faces.resource/utils.js.xhtml?ln=scripts"></script>

Comment: Does it contain the valid scripts? Your script needs to be called *after* those script are loaded.

Comment: Yep, it was a problem of scripts. I downloaded the wrong/old/fake ones...  Thank you very much for your always usefull help!!