# how to get all rows to display datepicker in h:dataTable

Tags: jquery, jsp, jsf

I worked with this example:  [Integrating jquery datepicker into jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226840/integrating-jquery-datepicker-into-jsf).

The first row of the dataTable comes up with the calendar icon but the remaining rows do not.  The table is dynamic and based on the rows selected from the query in the backing bean.

Here is what I have:

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>

<f:view>
<custom:html>
 <custom:head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- required plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/date.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery.datePicker.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>  
    <!-- datePicker required styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../styles/datePicker.css">
    <!-- page specific styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../styles/ewrwsdatepicker.css">

    <!-- page specific scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Shared properties for all datepickers with class="date-pick"
        $('.date-pick').datePicker({clickInput:true,startDate:'01/01/1996'});
        });
    </script>

</custom:head>
<custom:body>
<h:form id="adminSubmittedReportScreen">

<div id="content">
<div class="container"> 

<h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />            
<h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />            
<h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
<h:outputText style="font-family: Verdana; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" value="Some Data"/>
<h:dataTable id="adminDatafor" border="0"           
    styleClass="weeklyStatus"
    value="#{viewAdminSubmittedReport.performerWorkList}"
    rowClasses="#{viewAdminSubmittedReport.rowColor}"
    var="performerWorkList"> 
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Customer"/></f:facet>
        <h:outputText title="Customer" style="width: 100px;" value="#{performerWorkList.customer}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Location"/></f:facet>
        <h:outputText style="width: 65px;" title="Location" value="#{performerWorkList.location}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Actual Start Date" escape="false"/></f:facet>
        <h:inputText id="startDate" title="Actual Start Date" styleClass="date-pick" style="width: 75px;#{performerWorkList.init_actualStartDateHL}" value="#{performerWorkList.actualStartDateToActivity}" valueChangeListener="#{listController.filterFieldChanged}"><f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>

</body>
</html>

</div>
</div>

</h:form>
</custom:body>
</custom:html>
</f:view>
```

How do I get the date to work on the remaining rows?

Thank you!

Comment: For example 3, you have a class on the element you want to add the datepicker to but are (I assume) still using an ID selector in your jQuery code. Not sure why it doesn't work with example 2, though.

Comment: What JSF version are you using?

Comment: version of JSF is 1 - I hope that doesn't make a difference - that was why I put the elements on there outside the tags as well - but I can't even get those to work so I think I must be a real dummy!

Comment: @Anthony:  I have an ID on there but wanted to use the styleClass as in the example from StackOverflow.  That guy seems to work - can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Anthony - I edited and hope that was what you suggested.  I tried again and no errors but also no calendar on focus.